What is the Jacobian of the differential $df$?
Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth function from an $m$- to an $n$-manifold. The charts $(\phi,U)$ of $p\in M$ and $(\psi,V)$ of $f(p)\in N$ can be 'extended' as charts of $TM$ and $TN$ in a natural way:
\begin{align}
\Phi:U\times \mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2m}&:(p,v_p)\longrightarrow \Big(\phi(p),\phi_p(v_p)\Big)\\
\Psi:V\times \mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}&:(q,w_q)\longrightarrow\Big(\psi(q),\psi_q(w_q)\Big)
\end{align}
where $\phi_p$ and $\psi_q$ are defined -thinking of tangent vectors as derivations- by
\begin{align}
\phi_p:T_pM\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m&:v_p\longrightarrow \Big(v_p(x_1),\ldots,v_p(x_m)\Big)\\
\psi_q:T_qN\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n&:v_q\longrightarrow \Big(v_q(x_1),\ldots,v_q(x_n)\Big)
\end{align}
Given this setup, what is the Jacobian of $df$ at $(p,v)$ with respect to the charts $\Phi$ and $\Psi$?

My attempt: such Jacobian $J$ is a $2m\times 2n$ matrix, which we can break down into four $m\times n$ submatrices as follows
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial (df)_i}{\partial x_j}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} & 0\\
? & ? 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I have not been able to figure out what $C$ and $D$ are; it is difficult to think of $(df)_i$ -or $(\Psi\circ df \circ \Phi^{-1})_i$ without exploiting notation- for $i>n$ as $\phi_p$ has no inverse.

In the lower right corner, you have the derivative of the induced linear map $T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$. That map is the usual Jacobian, and since it's linear, its derivative is just the matrix of coefficients. Have I understood your setup correctly?

$\Psi\circ Tf\circ \Phi^{-1}$ sends $(x,v)\in U\times \Bbb{R}^m$ to $\left((\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})(x), D(\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})_x(v)\right)$ in $V\times \Bbb{R}^n$.
Here, I’m using the notation $Dg_x(v)$ to mean as usual the Frechet derivative of $g$ at the point $x$ applied on the vector $v$. Proving the above statement is a very good exercise in unwinding the meaning of the various charts. Now that you have this formula, you can easily figure out what the block form of its derivative is.
